# Why can't I refer to parent object?

Tags: handlebars.js

I've ran into this weird but simple problem. I'm looping through project.systems, each system can be edited via modal form which is included in partial named "_editSystem"

```
 {{#each project.systems}}
          <tbody>
          <td class="center"><h6>{{number}}</h6></td>
          <td class="center"><h6>{{name}}</h6></td>

          <td class="center">
          <form class="" action="{{../project._id}}/{{_id}}/delete-system" method="POST" id="delete-system-form">
          <input type="hidden" name="_method" value="PUT">
          <button type="submit" class="btn btn-sm btn-danger">
          <i class="fas fa-trash"></i> Delete </button>
          </form>
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-sm btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#editSystem-{{_id}}">
           <i class="fas fa-edit"></i> Edit </button>
          {{> _editSystem}}
          </a>
          </td>
          </tr>
```

The partial looks like this:

```
<div class="modal" id="editSystem-{{_id}}">
<div class="modal-dialog">
<div class="modal-content">
  <div class="modal-header">
    <h4 class="modal-title">Edit system</h4>
  </div>

  <!-- Modal body -->
    <div class="modal-body">
    <form action="{{../project._id}}/{{_id}}/edit-system" method="POST">
    <input type="hidden" name="_method" value="PUT">

        <div class="row">
                <div class="input-group">
                <div class="input-group-prepend">
                    <span class="input-group-text">System number</span>
                </div>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" name="number" id="number" value="{{number}}" placeholder="Enter system number">
                </div>
        </div>
        
        <div class="row">
                <div class="input-group pt-3">
                <div class="input-group-prepend">
                    <span class="input-group-text">System name</span>
                </div>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" name="name" id="name" value="{{name}}" placeholder="Enter system name">
                </div>
        </div>

    </div>
    

  <!-- Modal footer -->
  <div class="modal-footer">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
    <input type="submit" value="Save" class="btn btn-primary">
  </div>
</form>

</div>
```

The problem is that I can't refer to {{../project._id}}. After I submit the path looks like this:

> http://localhost:3000/601ffda3d3ff7c3ec0ef891f/edit-system

while proper path should look like this:

> http://localhost:3000/project/60185936bb697e1b9c7c6cb9/601ffda3d3ff7c3ec0ef891f/edit-system

Basically it seems like I can't refer to parent (project) id, while my "delete" button works just fine...
Does anyone know what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think you are doing anything wrong.

Without digging deep into the Handlebars source, I think it is safe to assume that a partial does not have access to the same context stack as the template that called it. This assumption is reinforced by the fact that the Handlebars documentation for [Partial Parameters](https://handlebarsjs.com/guide/partials.html#partial-parameters) states that such parameters are "particularly useful for exposing data from parent contexts to the partial".

So it seems you will need to pass your project ID value to your partial as a parameter, as in:

`{{> _editSystem projectId=../project._id}}`

Your partial would then reference the `projectId` parameter:

`{{projectId}}/{{_id}}/edit-system`

I have created a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/76484/b0syc4jm/12/) for your reference.

Comment: Thank you! This was very helpful and totally solved my problem! :)